# how to use sysprep and imagex for disk with one than partitions?

Tags: windows, partitioning, sysprep, imagex

Anybody knows how to use sysprep and imagex to create image and deploy that image when the original disk has more than one partitions on it?

Comment: With over 2,000 rep, how have you not yet figured out that questions like this are off-topic here? Did you notice that all the other questions are programming-related?

Comment: There are some experts are not only very good at programming but also good at task like this, I think. I can delete it if it is not good for this site.

Answer (score 2):

You cant capture more than one partition into one image. However you can write a .bat script that will capture both C:\ and D:\ partitions and then you can write another .bat file to re-partition the drive and deploy these two .wim images. If you don't know what .bat files do they basically string multiple command line commands and perform the actions for all of them. In order for the deploy.bat file to work you'll need to have the autoDiskPart.txt file saved were it can read it. Capture commands can be run on a local machine while booted to windows. You'll get better results however if you run them from a winPE disc that has ImageX added to it. You have to run the deployment from a disc such as this.

---

Disc Part Example Multiple Partitions

for deploy file to work this must be saved as "autoDiskPart.txt"

```
SELECT DISK 0 
CLEAN
CREATE PART PRI size = "n"
CREATE PART LOGICAL
SELECT PART 1 
ACTIVE 
ASSIGN LETTER=C
FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK 
SELECT PART 2
FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK
ASSIGN LETTER=D

EXIT
```

---

capture.bat file Example

```
rem Running Multiple Drive Image Capture

 imagex /capture /compress /verify c: f:\dive1.wim "Drive C"

 imagex /capture /compress /verify d: f:\drive2.wim "Drive D"

 exit
```

---

deploy.bat file Example

```
rem Multiple Image Deploy .bat

diskpart /s autoDiskPart.txt

imagex /apply F:\imaging\drive1.wim 1 C: /verify

imagex /apply F:\imaging\drive2.wim 1 D: /verify
```